# MySQL Inner Join with subquery

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I have a education table and a resume table. The education table has multiple rows for each resume id.

SELECT * FROM `education`

```
id  resume_id board_university  from_date   to_date     qualification_id    percentage  
24  1         Goa Board        2006-03-09   2006-04-09        1         65  
25  1         Goa Board        2008-04-06   2008-05-06        2         58
```

I am trying to make a search query on resume table. The following is my query

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM resume a, 
     qualification_master b, 
     users c,  
     (
       SELECT max(to_date) 
       FROM education e 
       WHERE ( e.qualification_id=1 OR e.qualification_id=2)
       GROUP BY e.resume_id
     ) AS d 
INNER JOIN ON a.id=d.resume_id 
WHERE a.uid=c.id
      AND d.qualification_id=b.id 
      AND a.profile_id=26 
      AND a.total_exp_in_yrs >=5 
      AND ((c.state=11 and c.city=331) or a.relocate="y")
```

But the query is throwing error. Can any one please help?

The result should pickup the qualification_id based on the max(to_date) in the education table.

Comment: Please provide properly formatted query and the error you are getting.

Comment: The op is new on SO, you should consider give him helpfull links: [Take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/help) or [How to Ask]( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ON a.id=d.resume_id

Comment: @TanmayChakraborty I see a lot of issue with the given query. It seems that you are using a `mix` of comma separated join and inner join . Please see [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question) and update the question

Comment: `.. INNER JOIN ON ..` - table name is lost. `.. ON a.id=d.resume_id ..` - subquery `d` have no `resume_id` column in the output list.

Comment: Replace all commas in comma-style joins with CROSS JOIN.

Comment: The manual cautions - 'If you mix comma joins with the other join types when there is a join condition, an error of the form Unknown column 'col_name' in 'on clause' may occur'  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you did wrong:

1. In the subquery `d`, you need to select both `resume_id` and `qualification_id`. Additionally, you should alias the aggregated column to something meaningful.
2. You're missing the alias for the `INNER JOIN` condition.
3. String comparisons in SQL should use single quotes (`'`) instead of double quotes (`"`).

---

```sql
SELECT a.* 
FROM resume a
INNER JOIN users c ON a.uid = c.id
INNER JOIN qualification_master b ON d.qualification_id = b.id
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT e.resume_id, MAX(e.to_date) AS max_to_date
    FROM education e 
    WHERE e.qualification_id IN (1, 2)
    GROUP BY e.resume_id
) AS d ON a.id = d.resume_id 
WHERE a.profile_id = 26 
  AND a.total_exp_in_yrs >= 5 
  AND (c.state = 11 AND c.city = 331 OR a.relocate = 'y');
```

- The subquery `d` selects the `resume_id` and the maximum `to_date` for each `resume_id`.
- The `INNER JOIN` conditions are properly aliased.
- String comparisons use single quotes.
- The `qualification_id` is joined with `qualification_master` table using `INNER JOIN`.

Please make sure to adjust the table and column names if they differ in your actual database schema.